# BOOTSTRAP Button not working for small screens

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code when my screen goes small, such as a mobile screen or a small windows screen, the button that appears does not seem to be responsive. Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

**Code:**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-0 fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Juwan's Bootcamp</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="WEBPAGES/Photo.html" class="nav-link">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="WEBPAGES/Contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What you mean by 'does not seem to be responsive'?

Comment: Once, the screen becomes small, or i use a mobile screen for the website. A button appears instead of the words. Once the button appears, when i try clicking on it there is no collapse taking place. It should show links to "About me, Photos, Contact" but it does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem caused by jquery. Make sure you have it placed before the bootstrap link. Inspect your code in the browser Console and see if everything works fine.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" async defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/5.1.1/bootstrap-social.min.css" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
```